# Should class names contain name of package?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to implement a logging mechnism in Java.
So I use JEE and use RequestFilter and Interceptors.
I put all that in a package called logging.

My classes are: RequestFilter, ResponseFilter and Constants

So my question. Is that ok to leave out logging in the class name because it is present in the package already ?

Or should I rather do. package logging and duplicate logging: RequestFilterLogging, ResponseFilterLogging, ConstantsLogging

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a few questions:

1- Is the purpose of RequestFilter to always log only?

2- Is there a plan for you to modify it to add further logic? For example customizing headers of requests, etc?

3- Do you plan on having more than 1 RequestFilter and specifying priorities?

If your design is to have multiple request filters, each doing their own custom logic, with priortization, then I would do it as such:

```
com.app.requestfilters
      --> LoggingRequestFilter
      --> HeadersRequestFilter
```

If your design is to have 1 RequestFilter that does a lot of things, not only logging:

```
com.app.requestfilters
       --> CustomRequestFilter
```

In my opinion, it is best to not reuse class names that exists in libs/frameworks that you are using:

In Apache Tomcat, there is a `RequestFilter`, and if you are extending this class, then yours should be a different name

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RequestFilter.html